# In ASP.NET Razor Page Jquery Ajax Function not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

I have a two `onchange` function for a page called create delivery request. One is when the `dropdownlist` of receiver changes, then it should show the phone number & address of receiver selected. Another one is when the `dropdownlist` of delivery item changes, then it should set the max attribute for the quantity.
The url of both these are linked to the customized `OnGet` method in razor page.

However, usually the above `Onget` method is hit but the below one is not. And the above `OnGet` method can't get the dryfood with the passed ID as well, it is null inside. And the two jQuery ajax function doesn't work at all. I'm totally a beginner. Hope that there is someone who can help me. Thanks in advance.

In **create.cshtml**:

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    Receiver Name
    <select id="receiver" asp-for="Delivery.ReceiverID" asp-items="Model.ReceiverList" class="form-control">
        <option>--Select the Receiever--</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    Receiver Phone
    <span id="receiverphone" class="form-control">----</span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    Receiver Address
    <div id="receiveradrs1" class="form-control">----</div>
    <div id="receiveradrs2" class="form-control">----</div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    Delivery Item
    <select id="deliveryitem" asp-for="DeliveryItem.DryFoodID" asp-items="Model.DeliveryItemList" class="form-control">
        <option>--Select Delivery Item--</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    Quantity
    <input id="quantity" asp-for="DeliveryItem.Quantity" min="1" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

In **create.csthml.cs**, two customized `OnGet` method here:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSetMaxQuantity(int id)
{
    List<DryFoodDonation> dfdlist = await _db.DryFoodDonation.ToListAsync();
    var dryfood = dfdlist.Where(d => d.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    Debug.WriteLine(dryfood.DryFoodName + " " + dryfood.DryFoodRemainQuantity);
    return new JsonResult(dryfood.DryFoodRemainQuantity);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetGetPhoneAdrs(int id)
{
    List<User> receiverlist = await _db.User.Where(u => u.UserType.TypeID == 3).ToListAsync();
    var selectreceiver = receiverlist.Where(d => d.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    Debug.WriteLine(selectreceiver.UserName + " " + selectreceiver.UserPhone);
    return new JsonResult(selectreceiver);
}
```

The jQuery AJAX function in a JavaScript file:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#receiver").change(function () {
        alert('Yes receiver here changed.');
        var item = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Create/?handler=GetPhoneAdrs',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: {
                'id': item
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#receiverphone').html(data.UserPhone);
                $('#receiveradrs1').html(data.UserAdrs1);
                $('#receiveradrs2').html(data.UserAdrs2);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#deliveryitem").change(function () {
        alert('Yes item here changed.');
        var item = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Create/?handler=SetMaxQuantity',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: {
                "id": item
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#quantity").attr({
                    "min": 1,
                    "max": data
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please help me with this. I can't solve this problem for a few weeks. Thank you!

Comment: in ajax url there is no name of method that you are calling on the controller, if you are using routes then put attribute on action

Comment: I don't have the controller, but I let them to call the OnGet method in razor page. The first OnGet method was called but the second one was not. Can't we use multiple OnGet and OnPost method in 1 razor page?

Answer (score 0):

```
// cshtml.cs 

const sendMe = async function (someData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ControllerName/MethodNameInController',
        data: { someData: someData },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
                ..
            } else {
                ..
            }
        }
    });
}


//Controller
[HttpPost("MethodNameInController")]
public IActionResult MethodNameInController([FromForm] string someData) {
..
}
```